# Removing soldered valve

Tags: valve, pedestal-sink

I’m trying to replace my pedestal sink with a newer sink. While trying to disconnect the water line to the sink, I noticed that the valve stem is soldered into the valve itself. Also, the stem is not flexible.

I tried loosen up the nut from the base of the faucet, but it won’t come off.

Should I loosen the nut (`nut2`[image] in the pic)? Do I need to shut off the main water line before I do this?

This [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/33613/126024) seems very similar to the problem I’m facing, but instructions about whether the main water line should be shut off or not are not mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I loosen the nut (nut2...)

YES. Those angle-stop valves are an older type with integrated flex lines. They are connected to the supply pipes with a *compression* type fitting. Loosening that nut (nut 2 in pic) will allow you to remove the old valves. The nut and the compression ring (formally known as the *ferrule*) will still be on the pipe. This is because the ring gets compressed onto the copper pipe when initially tightened during installation. With the valves removed, you can either:

- purchase new valves with the same type of compression fitting (should be labeled for 1/2 copper; sometimes listed as 5/8" comp. because 5/8" is the outside diameter of 1/2" copper pipe) and install the new valves utilizing the existing old nut and ferrule that are already there.
- purchase new valves with the same type of compression fitting and install using the new nuts and ferrules that come with the new valves. This would necessitate *removal of the old ferrules*, which can be accomplished various ways with (or without) special tools. I won't go into the ferrule removal process as there are a ton of recources available on the web that show various methods for doing this.
- remove all the original equipment and solder (aka *sweat*) 1/2" male threaded adapters (1/2" IPS) onto the supply pipes, then use new thread-on angle stops.

NOTES-

1. buy the best quality angle-stops you can find/afford
2. use high quality flex supply lines with braided stainless-steel jacket
3. there are a few *very old* "integrated flex stop valves" out there that have an unusual thread at the compression fitting that is not compatible with normal replacement compression stop valves. If you are unlucky enough to have these you will need to use either the 2nd or 3rd option mentioned above.

> Do I need to shut off the main water line before I do this?

**YES**, unless you want to flood your home.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to shut off the water if you are removing the valve by removing nut 2.

Answer (score 2):

"I tried loosen up the nut from the base of the faucet, but it won’t come off."

Hold the faucet with one wrench and the nut with another.  When you turn the nut, hold the faucet against the turning torque.

When you are removing the nut, it will move *towards* the wall.   It will be coming *off* the faucet.   Make sure you understand this exactly before starting so you turn the nut in the right direction.

When the faucet is removed, there will be a ferrule on the pipe and the nut will not be able to slide off.  If the ferrule is stuck on, leave it.   Reuse it and the nut.

Oh yeah, and shut off the main water.